# JAVA: How do I get this command to listen for button press?

Tags: java, command

I cannot figure out why the following command does not work when the program calls the command. I dont have a very good background in Java, but as I understand it, the command should execute the print line statement when i press the button on the joystick that calls the command. Im not sure whether the problem may be that the command needs a Action listener or button listener somewhere, or whether I need to somehow relate the command to the same console. There should only be one recognized console it can print to, which i know works from other print line statements in the original program... right?

Here is the *[library](http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/roborio/release/docs/java/index.html?edu/wpi/first/wpilibj/buttons/JoystickButton.html)* which may help

THE PROGRAM:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--*/
/* Copyright (c) 2017-2018 FIRST. All Rights Reserved.                        
*/
/* Open Source Software - may be modified and shared by FRC teams. The code   
*/
/* must be accompanied by the FIRST BSD license file in the root directory 
of */
/* the project.                                                               
*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--*/

package org.usfirst.frc.team5621.robot;

import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.IterativeRobot;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Joystick;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Spark;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Timer;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.buttons.Button;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.buttons.JoystickButton;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.command.Command;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.command.Subsystem;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.drive.DifferentialDrive;

/**
 * The VM is configured to automatically run this class, and to call the
 * functions corresponding to each mode, as described in the IterativeRobot
 * documentation. If you change the name of this class or the package after
 * creating this project, you must also update the manifest file in the resource
 * directory.
 */
public class Robot extends IterativeRobot {

    private DifferentialDrive m_robotDrive
            = new DifferentialDrive(new Spark(0), new Spark(1));
 static Joystick m_stick = new Joystick(1);
    private Timer m_timer = new Timer();
    static Subsystem ExampleSubsystem;
    Command ExampleCommand;
    Command CompressCommand;
    Command DecompressCommand;
    Command OpenClawCommand;
    Command CloseClawCommand;
    Command CompressorToggleCommand;

public static class OI {
    //Create Joystick and Buttons
    static Joystick m_stick = new Joystick(1);
    static Button   button1 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 1);
    static Button   button2 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 2);
    static Button   button3 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 3);
    static Button   button4 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 4);
    static Button   button5 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 5);
    static Button   button6 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 6);
    static Button   button7 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 7);
    static Button   button8 = new JoystickButton(m_stick, 8);

public OI() {
    // Define Commands for Joystick Buttons
    OI.button1.whileHeld(new CompressorToggleCommand());
    OI.button2.whileHeld(new CompressCommand());
    OI.button3.whileHeld(new DecompressCommand());
    OI.button4.whileHeld(new OpenClawCommand());
    OI.button5.whileHeld(new CloseClawCommand());
    OI.button6.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
    OI.button7.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
    OI.button8.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
    }
}

public class Compressor {
    Compressor c = new Compressor();
}
public class Solenoid {
    Solenoid exampleSolenoid = new Solenoid();
}

/**
 * This function is run when the robot is first started up and should be
 * used for any initialization code.
 */
@Override
public void robotInit() {
}

/**
 * This function is run once each time the robot enters autonomous mode.
 */
@Override
public void autonomousInit() {
    m_timer.reset();
    m_timer.start();
}

/**
 * This function is called periodically during autonomous.
 */
@Override
public void autonomousPeriodic() {
    // Drive for 2 seconds
    if (m_timer.get() < 2.0) {
        m_robotDrive.arcadeDrive(0.5, 0.0); // drive forwards half speed
    } else {
        m_robotDrive.stopMotor(); // stop robot
    }
}

/**
 * This function is called once each time the robot enters teleoperated mode.
 */
@Override
public void teleopInit() {
    System.out.println("TeleOperated Mode Enabled");
}

/**
 * This function is called periodically during teleoperated mode.
 */
@Override
public void teleopPeriodic() {
    m_robotDrive.arcadeDrive(m_stick.getY(), m_stick.getX());
}

/**
 * This function is called periodically during test mode.
 */
@Override
public void testPeriodic() {
}
}
```

THE COMMAND

```
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Copyright (c) 2017-2018 FIRST. All Rights Reserved.                        */
/* Open Source Software - may be modified and shared by FRC teams. The code   */
/* must be accompanied by the FIRST BSD license file in the root directory of */
/* the project.                                                               */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

package org.usfirst.frc.team5621.robot;

import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.command.Command;
/**
 * An example command.  You can replace me with your own command.
 */
public class CompressCommand extends Command {
    public CompressCommand() {
    }

// Called just before this Command runs the first time
@Override
protected void initialize() {
}

// Called repeatedly when this Command is scheduled to run
@Override
protected void execute() {
    System.out.println("Compressing...");
    exampleSolenoid.set(true);

}

// Make this return true when this Command no longer needs to run execute()
@Override
protected boolean isFinished() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Where does your application call the command? Can you highlight the line in your code?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd like to say that it's nice to see a fellow FRC programmer on Stack Overflow. Pertaining to your question, your problem may lie in the fact that you are declaring multiple *public* classes in the same file. This is very bad practice in Java programming. The problem you are looking to solve is here:

```
public OI() {
// Define Commands for Joystick Buttons
OI.button1.whileHeld(new CompressorToggleCommand());
OI.button2.whileHeld(new CompressCommand());
OI.button3.whileHeld(new DecompressCommand());
OI.button4.whileHeld(new OpenClawCommand());
OI.button5.whileHeld(new CloseClawCommand());
OI.button6.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
OI.button7.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
OI.button8.whileHeld(new ExampleCommand());
}
```

Once again, it is bad practice to have nested public classes, but what is really causing your problem is that you set the Button-On-Press actions for each button in the constructor of your OI class, but you never actually make an OI object, therefore the constructor is never called, and the code is never run. In your robotInit function, make an new OI object:

```
void robotInit() {
    OI myOI = new OI();
}
```

Also remove the OI tag from your statements inside of the OI class. It is not needed. So that this:

```
OI.button1.whileHeld(new CompressorToggleCommand());
```

Becomes this:

```
button1.whileHeld(new CompressorToggleCommand());
```

I would also recommend moving all of your object initializations to robotInit. I would suggest making all of your *many* nested classes each in their own file, and be sure to make objects of all of these classes in your main Robot class. I would also suggest reading up on some basic Object Oriented Programming concepts such as [how constructors work](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-in-java/), as well as [how to use classes and objects in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html). Also maybe read up on the FRC functions you are using in the [FRC API Reference](https://wpilib.screenstepslive.com/s/currentCS/m/java/l/272787-frc-java-wpilib-api-documentation)

Comment: Hello, First off i'd like to say the pleasure is all mine and thank you so much! I know that the public class should not have been nested, originally, I had it by itself. However, Eclipse was returning a error that I must change the return value to void. In addition to that, it was returning errors that I must declare 'button 1, 2, etc' as variables until I added that 'OI' part before it. I then realized that these errors did not happen if i nested the class as shown above. I put the 'OI' back in thinking 'why not'. I now have `code` Public void () OI{ OI.Button } //etc `code` (class unnested)

Comment: However, the real subject here seems to be that when I added in `code`  OI myOI = new OI(); `code` Eclipse gives an '!' stating that I need to make an OI class. It seems to like this better  `code` public void robotInit() {
  new OI();
 }  `code`

Comment: No problem. Hopefully your code is functioning the way intend now. Be sure to pass on what you have learned to your teammates so that you can avoid this issue in the future. Also, it would be appreciated if you could accept this answer by clicking on the check-mark next to it

Comment: Also, if you want to be able to reference your OI object, you have to initialize it. In the code `public void robotInit() { new OI(); }` you are not creating an object. Your OI class should be in a **separate file**. Be sure that you created the OI class as a part of your Robot project in Eclipse. Eclipse can be hard to operate sometimes, especially with complex things like FRC projects. Ask about it if you're not sure. And make sure that your OI class is `public`.